# VLC and playlist with individual volume control

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists

It seems impossible but I have to ask anyway. Is it possible to create a playlist that will make VLC play a set of files at individual volume level?

I am fiddling with the Audio compressor (not very well) but it would make much sense to me if I could have a list that said something like

```
<track>
<location>file://...
<duration>...
<volume>...</>
```

Reason is I need to play a specific set of video-clips in a loop - and they vary too much in amplitude (de- and reencoding with lowered volume is not really an option!)

Looking very much forward to tips and tricks from all you knowledgeable people out there :-)

Answer (score 0):

VLC does not have this capability.

But if this is only for a limited number of videos, there are several products
that can adjust the volume level of each video. Below are some turned up by a
quick search :

- [VSDC Free Video Editor](http://www.videosoftdev.com/)
- [Free Video Volume Booster](http://www.dvdavitools.com/free-video-volume-booster/)
- [Movavi Video Editor](https://www.movavi.com/support/how-to/how-to-make-video-louder.html)

Comment: #harrymc. Thanks. This is what I was worried about. One of the videos I need to have in my loop is a bluRay-folder (.mts nested in STREAM directory and all the other crap). And I can only begin to imagine the fuzz with volume fiddling THAT. Someone else gave me a tip that mplayer on mac would be able to fix my issue so I am looking into that (but haven't gotten very far yet)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to recode the BluRay in a format that is easier to manage. I believe that VLC can do that, but several others do exist.